# If you cut a thread of length L in 2 points uniformly random, what is the expected length of the middle part?

Tags: probability

If you cut a thread of length L in 2 points uniformly random, what is the expected length of the middle part?

Actually i know the answer for smallest part but not for this Q :((

Comment: You may state it as $E[max(X,Y)-min(X,Y)]$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent uniform random variables on $[0,L]$. You already know the expected value of $min(X,Y)$. Do the same for $max(X,Y)$ and you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1,X_2$ be the points selected. Then the length of the middle part is
given by $E (M-m)$, where $M = \max(X_1,X_2), m = \min(X_1,X_2)$.

We can compute $E M = 2 {1 \over L^2} \int_0^L \int_0^{x_1} x_1 d x_2 d x_1 = {2 \over 3} L$, and similarly (or by symmetry), $E m = {1 \over 3} L$, hence
$E(M-m) = {1 \over 3}L$.